# Generate a fixed-length array, but push() and shift() to keep changing values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm generating random numbers, pushing them to an array, and then looping over the array to reference each number in turn.

What I'd like to be able to do is generate the numbers continually (within reason! Say, up to 500 iterations, for example), but always keep just 5 numbers in the array.

I've tried pushing the new numbers to the array and then shifting the array, but something's not working. My current code is:

```
let initArray = [];

function makeArray() {
  do {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    initArray.push(val)
    i++
  }
  while (i < 500)
}

function shiftArray() {

if (initArray.length > 5) {
    initArray.shift();
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner, so I'm sure I've missed something basic, but I'd love to know what it is!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Since arrays in JS are also objects (everything is an object really in JS) you could do something like this: `const initArray = [1,2,3]; initArray[1] = 4;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems:

A: `i` was not defined

B: you weren't calling `shiftArray()`.

```js
let initArray = [];
i=0; // define i
function makeArray() {
  do {
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    initArray.push(val);
    shiftArray(); //call shiftArray
    console.log(initArray);
    i++;
  }
  while (i < 100) //reduced to prevent computers from screaming
}

function shiftArray() {

if (initArray.length > 5) {
    initArray.shift();
  }
}
makeArray();
```